# Sum Running Total in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a running total for my report, we will named it RT1. Now i created again another running total to get the sum of RT1 but i get the wrong answer. Any advice on how to correctly do this?

I have this formula in my first Running Total
//Formula1

```
@SpTotalReset
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar sp := 0;
//I placed it in my GroupHeader Date
```

//Formula2

```
@SpRunningTotal
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar sp;
sp := sp + {Sec/Pc};
//I placed it in my Details
```

//Formula3

```
@SpTotalDisplay
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar sp;
//I placed it in my GroupFooter Date
```

This is the formulas of my second running total
//Formula1

```
@MoTotalReset
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar mo := 0;
//I placed it in my GroupHeader Date
```

//Formula2

```
@MoRunningTotal
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar mo;
mo := mo + {@SpTotalDisplay};
//I placed it in my GroupFooter Date beside @SpTotalDisplay
```

//Formula3

```
@MoTotalDisplay
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar mo;
//I placed it in my GroupFooter Name
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the issue? also what is expected and what you got?

Comment: @Siva : i made formula fields to get a daily output which i got it correct but i also want to summarize the daily output and display it as a monthly output in my report.

I did the exact same thing as what i did in getting my daily output but the result when i made the monthly output is wrong.

Comment: In second running total what options you used to summarize and where did you reset?

Comment: Siva : heres my report in second running total

WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar x;

x := x + {@SpTotalDisplay}; <-- this is the Display of my first running total. I place my running total beside of @SpTotalDisplay. I reset in my Group Header Date.

Comment: the situation now is my second running total is not adding the next value just like my first running total. it just displays the value of @SpTotalDisplay.

Comment: can you edit your question to be more clear on what your formulas are and also to my guess you are missing `Shared` scope in variable decleration... try keeping that scope and try

Comment: Siva : i tried the shared scope and it works but the display of first running total field is the same as the display of my second running total field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change like this:

@MoTotalReset

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared numbervar mo := 0;
//I placed it in my GroupHeader Name
```

And apply shared for all formulas. This should work.

Comment: I applied Shared in all my formulas but that don't work. The '@MoRunningTotal' is not working perfect because it didn't add any value. It just copy the value of '@SpTotalDisplay'

Comment: where did you place the `mo` running total? In `Group header name` or `group header date`

Comment: i placed it in group footer date beside @SpTotalDisplay

Comment: No place the reset of `mo` in group header of name